# Asterisk AMI PHP via fsockopen and socket_get_status. socket_get_status returns unread bytes earlier than it is

Tags: php, sockets, stream, asterisk

I'm using custom class to connect to asterisk server via php.
Here it's code:

```
class Asterisk_ami
{
    public $ini = array();

    function __construct ()
    {
        $this->ini["con"] = false;
        $this->ini["host"] = "127.0.0.1";
        $this->ini["port"] = "****";
        $this->ini["lastActionID"] = 0;
        $this->ini["lastRead"] = array();
        $this->ini["sleep_time"]=1.5;
        $this->ini["login"] = "****";
        $this->ini["password"] = "****";
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        unset ($this->ini);
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->ini["con"] = fsockopen($this->ini["host"], $this->ini["port"],$a,$b,10);
        if ($this->ini["con"])
        {
            stream_set_timeout($this->ini["con"], 0, 400000);
        }
    }

    public function disconnect()
    {
        if ($this->ini["con"])
        {
            fclose($this->ini["con"]);
        }
    }

    public function write($a)
    {
        $this->ini["lastActionID"] = rand (10000000000000000,99999999900000000);
        fwrite($this->ini["con"], "ActionID: ".$this->ini["lastActionID"]."\r\n$a\r\n\r\n");
        $this->sleepi();
        return $this->ini["lastActionID"];
    }

    public function sleepi ()
    {
        sleep($this->ini["sleep_time"]);
    }

    public function read()
    {
        $mm = array();
        $b = array();
        $mmmArray=array();
        $k = 0;
        $s = "";
        $this->sleepi();
        do
        {
            $s.= fread($this->ini["con"],1024);
            sleep(0.005);
            $mmm=socket_get_status($this->ini["con"]);
            array_push($mmmArray, $mmm);
        }   while ($mmm['unread_bytes']);
        $mm = explode ("\r\n",$s);
        $this->ini["lastRead"] = array();
        for ($i=0;$i<count($mm);$i++)
        {
            if ($mm[$i]=="")
            {
                $k++;
            }
            $m = explode(":",$mm[$i]);
            if (isset($m[1]))
            {
                $this->ini["lastRead"][$k][trim($m[0])] = trim($m[1]);
            }
        }
        unset ($b);
        unset ($k);
        unset ($mm);
        unset ($mm);
        unset ($mmm);
        unset ($i);
        unset ($s);
        var_dump($mmmArray);
        return $this->ini["lastRead"];
        //return $s;
    }

    public function init()
    {
     return $this->write("Action: Login\r\nUsername: ".$this->ini["login"]."\r\nSecret: ".$this->ini["password"]."\r\n\r\n");
    }
}
```

And here is testAsterisk.php where I try it.

```
include("./lib/asteriskAmi.php");
$a = new Asterisk_ami();
$a->connect();
if ($a->ini["con"])
{
    $a->init();
    $a->write("Action: GetConfig\r\nFilename: extensions.conf\r\n");
    print_r($a->read());
    $a->disconnect();
}
```

I want to get extension.conf config via ami. The problem is that I don't get full config. 16 last string are alwas missing. However when I check GetConfig via asterisk console it returns full config. 
As you can see while cycle is interrupted when unread bytes of `socket_get_status` are 0, I checked them pushing in array and dumping it, and I can see that unread_bytes are actually 0. I tried changing `sleep_time` and different timeout parametres, the result was the same. 
What else can I check? What can cause this mistake? May be I can use some other func?

Comment: Also ask if you don't understand something in class, I'll explain.

Answer (score 1):

Really, only proper solution I've found is to use [PAMI](https://github.com/marcelog/PAMI), instead of custom class. It's more comfortable for using and anyway it gives me full content of extensions.conf.